# jQuery.get, XML Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I've got a simple web service which has the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfPerson xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <Person>
    <PersonId>111</PersonId>
    <FirstName>343</FirstName>
    <LastName>343</LastName>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <PersonId>12312</PersonId>
    <FirstName>afasdf</FirstName>
    <LastName>asdfasdf</LastName>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <PersonId>112</PersonId>
    <FirstName>test</FirstName>
    <LastName>test</LastName>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <PersonId>113</PersonId>
    <FirstName>test</FirstName>
    <LastName>test</LastName>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <PersonId>100100100</PersonId>
    <FirstName>blah</FirstName>
    <LastName>blah</LastName>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <PersonId>555</PersonId>
    <FirstName>555</FirstName>
    <LastName>555</LastName>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <PersonId>123</PersonId>
    <FirstName>john</FirstName>
    <LastName>smith</LastName>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <PersonId>234</PersonId>
    <FirstName>jane</FirstName>
    <LastName>doe</LastName>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <PersonId>345</PersonId>
    <FirstName>thomas</FirstName>
    <LastName>duberville</LastName>
  </Person>
</ArrayOfPerson>
```

which is requested by the followingn JS:

```
 var url = '../Service.asmx/GetPersons';
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            for (var prop in data) {
                $('body').append(data);
            }
        });
```

This is on my localhost.  When I console.log I get:
[image]

If I try to simple append the data variable to the page I get the error listed in the title, if I try `console.log($(data).find(attribute)))` I get a jQuery object without any relevant data into it.  If I want to keep using a get request and simply place these results on the page, what do I need to change to do that?

Comment: parse the xml as xml before you try to work with it. `$.get(url,successHandler,"xml")`

Comment: Why are you trying to append xml elements into html?

Comment: @KevinB just to get it to work.  I want to have a little sidebar on my website where I can pull in data from other places, but I figured if I couldn't get the requests to work locally I had no business using someone else's API

Comment: This should be enough to at least get something outputting onto the page: http://pastebin.com/8uQDn9E4